# Get invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read() , but Read() is called in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

alright, I am trying to get data from MySQL with C# using MySQL connector 6.9.5, and I get this error messages :

```
Error: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Invalid attempt to access a field before callingRead()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.get_Item(Int32 index)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetFieldValue(Int32 index, Boolean checkNull)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
at PayrollManagementSystem.ConnectorDB.login(String username, String password) in C:\Users\Scarlet\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\PayrollManagementSystem\PayrollManagementSystem\ConnectorDB.cs:line 41
```

it means that I am trying to access a field before calling Read() method, but I think I already did, here's my code :

```
public ModelUser login(String username, String password)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("username asal = " + username);
        ModelUser val = null ;
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        try
        {

            command = new MySqlCommand( "SELECT user.id_data_user, user.username, user.password FROM user WHERE username = '" + username + "'" +
                " AND password = '" + password + "'", connection);              

            MySqlDataReader reader;

            connection.Open();

            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            val = new ModelUser();

            reader.Read(); == this is the Read() method was called

            val.IDDataUser = reader.GetString(0); === error at this line
            val.Username = reader.GetString(1);
            val.Password = reader.GetString(2);


            Console.WriteLine("data_user di conDb: " + val.IDDataUser);

            connection.Close();

        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.ToString());
        }
        return val;

    }
```

I dont know what's wrong with my code, well this is my first time try C#, I appreciate for any reply to my question

> **Update:**

i changed my code like this

```
   if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    val.IDDataUser = reader.GetString(0);
                    val.Username = reader.GetString(1);
                    val.Password = reader.GetString(2);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Holy cow,she's got no rows!");
            }
```

my reader has no row. it's like it can't get any data from database. and this is what the logs look like :

```
'PayrollManagementSystem.vshost.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dl 
', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'PayrollManagementSystem.vshost.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Holy cow,she's got no rows!
username: 
data user: 
id : 
The thread '<No Name>' (0x13f0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: [MSDN Command.ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) look at the msdn reference I would also suggest / recommend changing that query to utilize `Parameters` put your code inside a while loop `while (reader.Read()){ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to check `reader`  read a row or not

the best way using data reader is

```
if(reader.HasRows)
  {
   while(reader.Read()) // == this is the Read() method was called
       {
        val.IDDataUser = reader.GetString(0); === error at this line
        val.Username = reader.GetString(1);
        val.Password = reader.GetString(2);
        Console.WriteLine("data_user di conDb: " + val.IDDataUser);
       }
   }
```

Comment: i tried it, but the reader has no row, and my query was right.

Comment: @Yusuf1494 `if(reader.HasRows) check reader has rows or not.
`

Comment: yes i knew it, i tried it, and it has no row, it's like my reader can't get any data from database.

Comment: wait, now it has rows, i don't know how but i restart my visual studio, and MySQL's server. Thanks for help by the way Anant :3